# FrameworkElement.Loaded never fires

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a curious problem which I'm not sure where to trace in order to debug. I have a Treeview with the `ItemTemplate` set to a  `HierarchicalDataTemplate` set to instances of `CustomTreeViewItem` seen below. I load 15 test viewmodel items and the binding properly updates the control's generated items. I can step past 15 calls to the `CustomTreeViewItem` constructor.

```
public class CustomTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
    public CustomTreeViewItem() : base()
    {
        this.Loaded += CustomTreeViewItem_Loaded;

    }

    private void CustomTreeViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //In a bound collection of 15 items, we arrive here exactly once.
    }
}
```

We arrive at the _Loaded handler exactly once out of the expected 15. The UI lays out and renders and the first `CustomTreeViewItem.Loaded` handler fires. But the remaining 14 do not fire despite being arranged and rendered just like the first.

I see 15 items rendered on screen. I can inspect any of the 15 using the live visual tree and see that `FrameworkElement.IsLoaded` = true.

Any idea how we arrive at IsLoaded but the handler is never invoked? Especially the unexpected fact that one correctly works but not the others with the exact same constructor?

Comment: So upon stepping through the code, I have some strange behavior of completely jumping out of the method while the system calls FrameworkElement.VisualChildrenCount.get()`. Literally right in the middle of the current synchronous method. The debugger gives no indication that I might have changed threads.

Comment: So I found the cause of the unexpected behavior, I was calling `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(null)` and you can see I was feeding it null inadvertently. Visual Studio was set to mute source exceptions, so apparently it just fails execution and returns to main.